# Sufficient condition for a function to be a bijection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

We want to prove two sets $A$, and $B$ have the same cardinality. Assume we have found a function $f:A\to B$, and a function $g:B\to A$, with $f\circ g=id$. Can we conclude that $f$ is bijective?

**Context:** I am reading a proof that the morphisms $\phi:V\to W\subset k^m$ of algebraic varieties, over an algebraically closed field $k$, are in bijective correspondence with the homomorphisms of their respective coordinate rings as $k$-algebras. To each morphism, we assign its pullback. Conversely, to each homomorphism $a:k[W]\to k[V]$ we assign the morphism $\phi_a=(a(y_1+I(W)),\dots, a(y_m+I(W)))$, where $y_j$ are the coordinate functions of $k^m$. We check that $\phi_a$ is indeed a morphism and that the pullback $\phi_a^*=a$. How does that suffice to show the above correspondence is indeed a bijection?

Comment: The answer to the first question is no, we can only conclude that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. But unless the sets are finite, this does not guarantee bijectivity even when the sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Well, you know that $f$ is bijective if $f\circ g=id_B$ and $g\circ f=id_A$. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

Let $A = B = \mathbb{N} = \{ 0,1,2,3,...\}$. Let 
$$ f : A \to B \quad \mbox{ by } \quad f(n) = \begin{cases} k & \mbox{ if } n=2k \ ,\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
and let
$$ g : B \to A \quad \mbox{ by } \quad f(n)=2n $$

Then $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}_B$ since $f(g(n)) = f(2n)=n$ but $f$ is not a bijection (in particular, $f$ is not injective).

However, if $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}$ and $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$ then $g = f^{-1}$ and both $f$ and $g$ are bijections.

Comment: Or simply $f(k)=k-1$ if $k \geq 1$ and $f(0)$ anything.

Answer (score 2):

@First paragraph: No, this is only true for finite sets.

Regarding your algebraic geometry context: Well, one easily shows that the two maps are inverse to each other, i.e. not only that $\phi_a^* = a$, but also $\phi_{\phi^*} = \phi$.

Comment: Thank you, one easily shows it indeed.